# Celery autodiscover_tasks not working for all Django 1.7 apps

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django 1.7 project with Celery 3.1. All the apps in my Django project work with the new AppConfig. The problem is that not all the tasks are found with `autodiscover_tasks`:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

If i use autodiscover_tasks like this it wil work:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS + ('apps.core','apps.sales'))
```

The tasks defined in websites are found but the tasks in core and sales are not. All have the same layout with `apps.py` and `tasks.py`.

The project folder structure is:

```
apps
  core
  apps.py
  tasks.py
dashboard
  apps.py
sales
  apps.py
  tasks.py
websites
  apps.py
  tasks.py
```

The class definitions are as follows:

```
class WebsitesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.websites'
    verbose_name = 'Websites'

class SalesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.sales'
    verbose_name = 'Sales'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is discussed in a number of Celery issues, such as [#2596](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2596) and  [#2597](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/2597).

If you are using Celery 3.x, the fix is to use:

```
from django.apps import apps
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

As mentioned in [#3341](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3341), if you are using Celery 4.x (soon to be released) you can use:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Comment: My goodness, you save the day! An estimated 1-hour of work turned into a full day of head-scratching. Without your answer, I would be sleeping with nightmare tonight. Much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I am using django 2.1 and celery 4.2, still having this issue and need to add `get_app_configs` :(

Comment: @TarasMatsyk this is the case for me, but the "work around" for Celery 3.x still worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem because of a misconfigured virtual environment.

If an installed app has a dependency missing from the virtual environment in which you're running celery, then the installed app's tasks will not be auto discovered. This hit me as I was moving from running my web server and celery on the same machine to a distributed solution. A bad build resulted in different environment files on different nodes.

I added the dependencies that were missing then restarted the celery service.

Comment: Can this be checked by `python -m pip check`?

Comment: I suppose you could probably do that; provided `requirements.txt` was accurate and up to date. When this specific change happened, that was one of several environment files that were not correct across machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to the module where my celery app was defined:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the wrong path to the `celery.py` in the celery command.
the command should be something  like this:

```sh
celery worker -A <project_name.celery_app_module> -l info
```

where celery `celery_app_module` is like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# Set default Django settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<project_name>.settings')

app = Celery('<project_name>', include=['<app_name>.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```